# Grabing value from input field and extracting ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working with extracting YT video IDs with the use of regex through javascript. I have a working example. But instead of using `var exaxmpleYoutubeURLs`. Is there a way to create an input field where the link can be copied into and then displayed the eleven digit `ID` through ajax?  Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DJSwc/15/)

```
var youtubePattern = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=|\/feeds\/api\/videos\/|\/user\S*[^\w\-\s]|\S*[^\w\-\s]))([\w\-]{11})[?=&+%\w-]*/ig;

var exmpleYouTubeURLs = [
    "http://www.youtube.com/embed/NLqAF9hrVbY",
];

// Extract the YouTube ID 
function linkifyYouTubeURLs(text) {
    return text.replace(youtubePattern, '$1');
}

for(i=0; i < exmpleYouTubeURLs.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(i + ". " + linkifyYouTubeURLs(exmpleYouTubeURLs[i]) + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: You mean instead of creating the url array manually, you want to get them from input box. Am I right?

Comment: @user2008945 Yes, That is correct

Comment: Sorry, if I am being dumb, but why use ajax?

Comment: @user2008945 that way there is no button click involved. I would like it to be a paste into input box and right away a display of ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
<textarea id="links"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="extractLinks()" value="Extract" />
<div id="outputDiv"></div>

<script>
    function extractLinks() {

        var youtubePattern = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=|\/feeds\/api\/videos\/|\/user\S*[^\w\-\s]|\S*[^\w\-\s]))([\w\-]{11})[?=&+%\w-]*/ig;

        var exmpleYouTubeURLs = document.getElementById('links').value.split('\n');
        var output = document.getElementById('outputDiv');

        function linkifyYouTubeURLs(text) {
            return text.replace(youtubePattern, '$1');
        }

        output.innerHTML = '';
        for(i=0; i < exmpleYouTubeURLs.length; i++) {
             output.innerHTML += i + ". " + linkifyYouTubeURLs(exmpleYouTubeURLs[i]) + "<br >";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Or you could try this if want to avoid the button click: <textarea id="links" onblur="extractLinks()" ></textarea>

Comment: `onchange="extractLinks()"` would be better, because blur can occur even if user hasn't changed the values